# Sign a debug APK file while using cordova run command line

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, keytool

I would like to test and debug a signed version of a APK file, using Apache Cordova command line. When we run either `cordova build android` or `cordova run android --device` a APK file is created at:

```
<project_dir>/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/debug/android-debug.apk
```

Can we sign this debug file before sending it to the device while running `cordova run android --device`?

Or is this `android-debug.apk` already signed with a SHA1, and if so how to get that signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already signed with the certificate of name **androiddebugkey** in the `~/.android/debug.keystore` keystore.

To get the signature:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore > debug.crt
openssl sha1 -binary debug.crt > debug.sha
openssl base64 -in debug.sha > debug.txt
```